# Full calendar to Excel and .pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, excel, pdf

I am using jQuery full calendar. I want to export full calendar HTML to Excel and .pdf. I have below code in order to achieve **exporting to Excel**:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<input type="button" id="btnExportToExcel" value="Export to excell" onclick="ExportToExcell()" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function ExportToExcell() {

        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#calendar').html());
        e.preventDefault();

    }
```

However above code is not working for me in order to export to Excel.

How can I export full calendar HTML to Excel and .pdf?

Comment: Not sure about the js and html fragment you put here.. but just can you let me know which api/server/client solution are you looking at to achieve this? Does this approach support that?

Comment: html is not displaying in excel file . html text displays in excel

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can export the whole full calendar io div as excel.

- But what I can suggest to write a function to separate the current
  month details as a separate HTML table
- And then export the table to excel

You can refer the link for exporting the html table to excel

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html